# How to display an image above generated QR code with QRCode React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, qr-code

I'm working with React and QRCode npm package, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode), to generate a QR code. I want to display the logo over the generated QR code, so far the image is displayed like this:

[image]

Script code:

```
const generateQRCode = async (rowData) => {
  const { N_turno, orden, bahia, proceso_t, n_placa, cond_info } = rowData;
  const url = `${BASE_API}/${auth.me.tenant}/documentos/qr/`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `n_orden=${orden}&n_turno=${N_turno}&n_proceso=${proceso_t}`,
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  const qrCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  qrCanvas.height = 600; 
  qrCanvas.width = 200

  // draws the code to the canvas
  await QRCode.toCanvas(qrCanvas, data.qr_content, { margin: 15, scale: 10 });

  const image = new Image()

   // logo source
   image.src = 'src/pages/Client/Turns/logo.png'

   // Add text to the canvas
   const ctx = qrCanvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.font = '25px arial'; // style
   ctx.textAlign = 'center'; // center the text

   // places the text in the defined space
   ctx.fillText(`Driver: ${cond_info}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 120);
   ctx.fillText(`Order: ${orden}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 90)
   ctx.fillText(`Plate: ${n_placa}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 60);
   ctx.fillText(`Turn: ${data.n_turno}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 30);
   ctx.fillText(`Bay: ${bahia}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 1)

   // generates qr code and download it to the pc
   const qrImg = qrCanvas.toDataURL();
   const qrContainer = document.createElement('div');
   qrContainer.style.display = 'flex';
   qrContainer.style.flexDirection = 'column';
   qrContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
   const qrWrapper = document.createElement('div');
   qrWrapper.style.maxWidth = '300px';
   qrWrapper.innerHTML = `
   <img src="${qrImg}" alt="QR code" />`;
   qrContainer.appendChild(qrWrapper);
   const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
   downloadLink.href = qrWrapper.querySelector('img').src;
   downloadLink.download = `qr-code${rowData.orden}.png`;
   downloadLink.click();
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved researching in some pages, hope it helps to anyone that has this kind of problem.

```
import logo from "../../Client/Turns/logo.png" // import your image

const generateQRCode = async (rowData) => {
    
    const data = await response.json();

    try {
       // create canvas
       const qrCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       qrCanvas.height = 600; // set canvas heigh
       qrCanvas.width = 200; // set canvas width
       const qrContext = qrCanvas.getContext('2d'); // context of the canvas
       
       // generates qr code with the QRCode npm package
       await QRCode.toCanvas(qrCanvas, data.qr_content, {margin:15,scale:10});

       // creates a new Image obj
       const image = new Image();

       // sets source of the image
       image.src = logo; // image imported at the top

       // when the image load will enter to the function and do everything inside
       image.onload = function() {
            // sets the position and size of the image
            qrContext.drawImage(image, qrCanvas.width/2.8, qrCanvas.height-500, 128, 110);

            qrContext.font = '25px Arial';
            qrContext.textAlign = 'center';
            qrContext.fillText(`Driver: ${cond_info}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 120);
            qrContext.fillText(`Order: ${orden}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 90);
            qrContext.fillText(`Plate: ${n_placa}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 60);
            qrContext.fillText(`Turn: ${data.n_turno}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 30);
            qrContext.fillText(`Bay: ${bahia}`, qrCanvas.width / 2, qrCanvas.height - 1);

            const qrImg = qrCanvas.toDataURL();
            const qrContainer = document.createElement('div');
            qrContainer.style.display = 'flex';
            qrContainer.style.flexDirection = 'column';
            qrContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
            const qrWrapper = document.createElement('div');
            qrWrapper.style.maxWidth = '300px';
            qrWrapper.innerHTML = `<img src="${qrImg}" alt="QR code" />`;
            qrContainer.appendChild(qrWrapper);
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = qrWrapper.querySelector('img').src;
            downloadLink.download = `qr-code${rowData.orden}.png`;
            downloadLink.click();
         };
     } catch (e) {
         console.log(e)
     }
   };
```